# StartActivity dentro de BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Quero ir pra outra activity quando entrar no `onReceive` do meu receiver, mas sempre para de funcionar no `startActivity`, o código que estou fazendo esta assim:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hora de ir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Pode ser uma pergunta idiota, mas esse `MyAlarmService` é um Service? Porque não se inicia um Service dessa forma...

Comment: Qual a Exception?

Comment: é uma classe normal, só coloquei service por colocar

Comment: RunTimeException, e ActivityNotFoundException, sendo que o manifest tem lá

Comment: Colocou o package corretamente? Ou colocou relativo ao package do manifest? Tente colocar o caminho absoluto da Activity para ver se acontece o mesmo problema.

Comment: só precisava adicionar uma flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessário adicionar FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.